# Combinatorics and sum of combinations

Tags: combinatorics

The following question arises in the context of enumerating combinations efficiently. Let's say you want to enumerate all combinations of $k$ elements among the first $n$ consecutive integers starting at $0$. The $\verb|itertools.combinations|$ function provides the desired result, but happens to do so with amortized complexity $O(k)$, simply because of the need to build the combination at each step.

Now let's suppose we can modify the generated combination in-place. For combinations with size $k\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, an adjustment of the logic in $\verb|itertools.combinations|$ provides a constant amortized complexity. However, if $k>\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, we tend towards an $O(k)$ amortized complexity.

In this case, the idea is to populate the complementary combination and to modify it in-place, then to apply the associated modifications to the combination to generate. One of the steps to achieve this comes from this piece of (out-of-context) code :

```
int m;
for(m = n - k - 1; m >= 1; m--){
  if(complement[m] != complement[m-1] + 1){
    isFound = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

The following question is supposed to answer whether or not the effective length of the loop is a constant independant from $n$ and $k$ in average, which provides the answer to the question : "When enumerating combinations in-place, can we achieve it with a constant amortized complexity ?".

**Question** : Is it true to say that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $k,n$ positive integers with $\lfloor n/2\rfloor<k<n-1$,
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-m}{m}\leq C\binom{n}{k}\,?
$$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), i.e. edit your post to include your attempts.

Comment: Does $C$ have to be an integer? Otherwise, you could just make it arbitrarily close to $0$, no?

Comment: @RTF $C$ is not necessarily an integer, as it represents an average number of executed operations. Nevertheless, I don't understand your question : if you lower the value of $C$, it's getting harder and harder to bound the left-hand side from above.

Comment: Your summation must have typos; the upper bound cannot be dependent on the index $k$, and the terms in the summation should probably be dependent on $k$. (Maybe the lower bound should be $m=0$?) Also, as per Anne's comment above, please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, the summation index should be $m$. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** : using Pascal's triangal identities, we prove that $C=1$ works.
$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}
  &= \binom{n-1}{n-k}+\binom{n-1}{n-k-1}\\
  &\geq \binom{n-1}{n-k}+\binom{n-1}{1}+1\\
  &= \binom{n-2}{n-k} + \binom{n-2}{n-k-1} + \binom{n-1}{1}+1\\
  &\geq \binom{n-2}{n-k} +\binom{n-2}{2} + \binom{n-1}{1}+1\\
  &\geq \dots\\
  &\geq\binom{k}{n-k} + \dots+ \binom{n-2}{2} + \binom{n-1}{1}+1\\
  &= \sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-m}{m}\,.
\end{align*}$$